# Why java ref vars call the method based upon actual object where as the variables are based upon the ref variable type?

Tags: java, inheritance

In both super class A and sub class B i have variable abc as 10 and 20 respectively, and a method callme(), overrided in sub class.

If i do

```
A a = new B(); 
B b = B(new A());
```

then if i write

```
a.callme() -> calls B's method
b.callme() -> calls A's method.
```

This is because method is called based upon the actual object.

If i do

```
str = a.abc; // will print 10 , based upon ref var type A

str = b.abc; // will print 20 , based upon ref var type B
```

Why is this difference? Why not both method and variables accesses based upon the actual object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, instance variables are *never overidden*, they are *hidden*. It is the type of reference that decides that whose instance variables will be accessed.

In subclass, the method `callme()` is overidden. So, according to **Dynamic method dispatch mechanism**, it is the type of object that decides which method will be called at Runtime. It is because, objects are created at runtime.

E.g

```
class A {
       int abc = 10;

       public void callme() { 
           System.out.println("In class A");
        }
   }

class B extends A {   
       int abc = 20;  // hidden, not overidden

        public void callme() { 
           System.out.println("In class B");
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.callme(); // calls A's callme() method. 

        B b = new B();
        b.callme(); // calls B's callme() method.
       }
 }
```

Comment: some descriptions about hiding field from [Oracle Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

Comment: I knew about that. Subclass instance variables hides the superclass variables with same name.

Comment: I think i was not able to ask clearly..that i understood that the fields are hideen with the subclass fields. Thats a logical answer which is correct also. I wanted to ask about why the methods and fields are called based upon object ref variable type and actual object type? Is this something related to how methods and fields will be stored in memory? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Methods have an implementation while fields just store values/objects. It makes sense to be able to override the implementation of a method. But I don't see a need for "overriding" a field. Why don't just remove the declaration from the subclass and use the field of the superclass?

On the other hand it is also possible to hide methods. But you have to make them private.

```
class OuterClass {
    void test() {
        InnerSubClass isc = new InnerSubClass();
        isc.m(); // prints "In subclass"
        ((InnerSuperClass) isc).m(); // prints "In superclass"
    }
    class InnerSuperClass {
        private void m() {
            System.out.println("In superclass");
        }
    }
    class InnerSubClass extends InnerSuperClass {
        private void m() {
            System.out.println("In subclass");
        }
    }
}
```